# Exe file build by Pyinstaller can not save video with cv2.VideoWriter

Tags: python, pyinstaller, opencv3.0

I have written a python script called `videoSave.py` to read camera and save video. The code is as below:

```py
import cv2


def saveCam():
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, img = video.read()

    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    videoSaver = cv2.VideoWriter("videoSave_test.avi", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 10, (w, h))

    key = 0
    while key != 27:
        ret, img = video.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        cv2.imshow('img', img)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        videoSaver.write(img)

    videoSaver.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    saveCam()
```

**This script works well when runed directly. It can show the image obtained by the camera and save the content to a video file.**

Then I build this script into exe file using command `pyinstaller -F videoSave.py`. I can get the exe file. And when excuting it, I can see the image obtained by the camera, but the video file saved by it has **zero size**!

**My environment is:**
Python 3.7.4
Windows 7
Pyinstaller 3.5
opencv 4.1.2

Comment: I have solved this problem by copying `opencv_video_ffmpeg412_64.dll` from `Anaconda3\envs\your_env_name` to the dir where exe file lies. But I donot know why.

Comment: Have you solved it? I have the exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by copying opencv_video_ffmpeg412_64.dll from Anaconda3\envs\your_env_name to the dir where exe file lies. But I donot know why.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pack the opencv_videoio_ffmpeg420_64.dll in the .exe

To do so, use `--add-binary` option this way (I think you can use `--add-data` option too):

```
pyinstaller --onefile videoSave.py --add-binary venv\Lib\site-packages\cv2\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg420_64.dll;.
```

Of course you have to specify your own path to the .dll (The .dll could sometimes have other names).

Note that, at the end, it is ";." on Windows and ":." on most unix systems, as specified [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-pyinstaller) (Section: "What to bundle, where to search")

According to this [issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3426) it seems that it is because Pyinstaller didn't pack opencv_ffmpeg340.dll in the .exe, which is neccesary to save videofiles.

Looks like you can manually copy and paste the .dll in the same folder where the .exe lies and the program will read it, that would explain the solution offered by @ToughMind